# When connect 2 monitors bottom half of one monitor is black

Tags: windows-7, windows, multiple-monitors

Here is my situation: I've connected two samsung monitors to my laptop, both monitors function perfectly when connected alone, but when I connect both, bottom half of 24" monitor goes black, also mouse pointer is displayed on it but windows\desktop are not.

Any ideas what could cause it?

Comment: When you say it goes blacvk. Does it shrink the picture down into just the top half or do you lose half the picture?

Comment: Just lose bottom half of picture, and as I told, mouse is displayed on dead half. Sometimes bottom half blinked showing me desktop background image.

Comment: What operating system is this?

Comment: Windows 7 home basic (shame on me)

Comment: Have you tried upgrading your Graphics Card Drivers? From the manufacturers website?

Comment: Did it 2 days ago. Could it be some power issues?

Comment: I should repeat myself, both monitors works fine when I connect only one to laptop(so I use laptop's screen + external monitor). Lag appears when I turn of laptop's monitor and use 2 external.

Answer (score -1):

When two monitors(with diffrent resolution) are connected the display resolution will be smaller amoung them;so monitor having bigger resolution have some blank space.

Comment: But it's not true. I could configure resolution for each monitor in settings. And I successfully had connected monitor to laptop so I had two screens (1600x900 and 1980x1020)

Comment: do you extend the display or display same screen on both?

Answer (score -1):

Please check out this link: http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-set-up-multiple-monitors-with-windows-7.html .

I hope ti will solve all your issues :)

Regards,

Comment: Thanks, but it's just an instruction how to use dual screen settings, luckily I know it. The question was about another issue, after I did all configurations.